# Bootstrap nav wouldn't close

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that there are other posts with the same subject, but I tried a lot of them but still got the problem.

I can perfectly open the nav, but when I want to close it, it just flicker, and it doesn't close at all.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
@*navbar navbar-default*@
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <p class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">@Model.Content.Name</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @foreach (var item in selection)
            {
                if (item.Children.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <li class="dropdown @(item.Id == Model.Content.Id ? "current" : null)">
                        <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name.ToUpper()</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @foreach (var child in item.Children)
                            {
                                <li class="@(item.Id == Model.Content.Id ? "current" : null)">
                                    <a href="@child.Url">@child.Name.ToUpper()</a>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="@(item.Id == Model.Content.Id ? "current" : null)">
                        <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name.ToUpper()</a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

```
Html.RequiresCss("/css/bootstrap.min.css", 1);
Html.RequiresCss("/css/bootstrap-responsive.css", 1);


Html.RequiresJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js", 0);
Html.RequiresJs("/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", 1);
```

I hope that someone know what can cause this error.

Comment: Please make your code a snippet.

Comment: It looks like you may have a couple issues going on in this snippet. Check to make sure the CSS logic is rendering expected HTML. It looks like you may have some incorrectly placed quotes. Creating a [.NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net) would increase your chances of an accurate answer.

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle.

Comment: Jesse Johnson: I am also including the css styles, I've updated the snippet.
I can't really see a problem, I have followed the solution on bootstraps own site, any suggestions  ?

Comment: I found the problem.

I had a @Html.RenderJsHere() at the button of the body, i removed that and that solved the problem.